# Webpack development mode does not create multiple bundle file

Tags: webpack, bundling-and-minification

I am having issues with my Webpack configuration. I get multiple bundle files in production mode but not in development mode. I would like both environments to produce multiple bundle files.

Below is the part of my configuration file where production and development are treated differently. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var AppCachePlugin = require('appcache-webpack-plugin');

var appConfig = require('./config.js');
console.log("appConfig is ->>>", appConfig);
var appPort = appConfig.APP_PORT; //Port on which the application is running

process.noDeprecation = true;
module.exports = function(options) {
    var entry, jsLoaders, plugins, cssLoaders, devtool;
    console.log('options webconfig-->', options, 'directory name', __dirname);

    // If production is true
    if (options.prod) {
        console.log('production minifcation');
        // Entry
        entry = {
            veris: './js/abc.js',
            au680: './js/cde.js',
        };


        // Plugins
        plugins = [ // Plugins for Webpack
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {
                    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
                }
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                minimize: true
            })
        ];

    // If app is in development
    } else {
        devtool = 'source-map';
        // Entry
        entry = [
            "webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:" + appPort, // Needed for hot reloading
            "webpack/hot/only-dev-server", // See above
            //path.resolve(__dirname,'./js/app') // Start with js/app.js...
            './js/abc.js',
            './js/cde.js'
        ];

        // Only plugin is the hot module replacement plugin
        plugins = [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {
                    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
                }
            }),
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() // Make hot loading work,
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entry points for development mode contains:

```
entry = [
  "webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:" + appPort, // Needed for hot reloading
  "webpack/hot/only-dev-server", // See above
  //path.resolve(__dirname,'./js/app') // Start with js/app.js...
  './js/abc.js',
  './js/cde.js'
];
```

You need to transform this into a map as you did for production:

```
entry = {
  main: [
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:" + appPort, // Needed for hot reloading
    "webpack/hot/only-dev-server" // See above
  ],
  //path.resolve(__dirname,'./js/app') // Start with js/app.js...
  veris: './js/abc.js',
  au680: './js/cde.js'
};
```